# identification of recorded voice: "portions" or "burgeons"?

Tags: image-identification

In [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFsFZwpB-tE) (1:09) is the woman saying "portions" or "burgeons"? 
As a non native English speaker it's difficult to me to understand the spelling in this part of the video and that's why it's impossible to me to understand according to the context (she wont judge me because...).

Comment: But neither of those makes any sense, right? Did you get "late-term"? That should have been enough context.

Comment: For me "late term" said nothing, to be honest, and I can assume that it's because I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELL is not a service for getting individual transcriptions.

Comment: @Nat This is not a request for a transcript it is a request from an ELL for help identifying a spoken word.

Comment: @JimReynolds: Yes, asking for help transcribing a particular video... in a way that is impossible to search for, except for those who want to know exactly what that particular video says at that moment. That's a very poor match for ELL's goal of reusable questions; this is not suitable for teaching anyone to fish.

Comment: @JimReynolds: The reason proofreading is off-topic is because it's too localized: you can't search for such questions usefully, nor learn much of anything general from them. Transcription requests ("what does this audio clip say here?" "what does this video say here?") have generally been closed for the same basic reason, but we don't get enough to have a special reason dedicated.

Comment: @Nat I've removed my earlier comment which was not constructive (or one could say being a jerk). Maybe I can step back and take another tack: I think this might be an issue on which the community (SE-wide, EL&U+ELL, or ELL) has not yet reached consensus or has lost touch with any past consensus. "Too localized" was removed as a close reason on SE 2.5 years ago, at which time there was significant disagreement on what it meant and more than half of "too localized" closures were being reopened.

Comment: @JimReynolds: Yeah, it might be worth opening a meta question for this just to make the precedent clearer; there don't seem to be any at present.

Comment: She says "abortions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> She won't judge me because I get 30 [late-term abortions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_termination_of_pregnancy).